# BootstrapError Parameter "form" should contain a valid Django Form

Tags: python, django, forms

i have an app called reviews

reviews/forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea
from reviews.models import Review

class ReviewForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ['rating', 'comment']
        widgets = {
            'comment': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 40, 'rows': 15}),
        }
```

reviews/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from .models import Review, Wine
from .forms import ReviewForm
import datetime

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def add_review(request, wine_id):
    wine = get_object_or_404(Wine, pk=wine_id)
    form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        rating = form.cleaned_data['rating']
        comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
        user_name = form.cleaned_data['user_name']
        user_name = request.user.username
        review = Review()
        review.wine = wine
        review.user_name = user_name
        review.rating = rating
        review.comment = comment
        review.pub_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        review.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('reviews:wine_detail', args=(wine.id,)))

return render(request, 'reviews/wine_detail.html', {'wine': wine, 'form': form})
```

reviews/templates/reviews/wine_detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block title %}
<h2>{{ wine.name }}</h2>
<h5>{{ wine.review_set.count }} reviews ({{ wine.average_rating | floatformat }} average rating)</h5>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h3>Recent reviews</h3>

{% if wine.review_set.all %}
<div class="row">
    {% for review in wine.review_set.all %}
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
        <em>{{ review.comment }}</em>
        <h6>Rated {{ review.rating }} of 5 by {{ review.user_name }}</h6>
        <h5><a href="{% url 'reviews:review_detail' review.id %}">
        Read more
        </a></h5>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% else %}
<p>No reviews for this wine yet</p>
{% endif %}

<h3>Add your review</h3>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'reviews:add_review' wine.id %}" method="post" class="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form layout='inline' %}
    {% buttons %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
      {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Add
    </button>
    {% endbuttons %}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}

{% block bootstrap3_content %}
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'reviews:review_list' %}">Winerama</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="{% url 'reviews:wine_list' %}">Wine list</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'reviews:review_list' %}">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'reviews:user_review_list' user.username %}">Hello {{ user.username }}</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'auth:logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
                {% else %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'auth:login' %}">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="/accounts/register">Register</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <h1>{% block title %}(no title){% endblock %}</h1>

    {% bootstrap_messages %}

    {% block content %}(no content){% endblock %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I am getting the error at the line `{% bootstrap_form form layout='inline' %}` in the html file

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: When the `form` variable is empty, this type of problem happens. Check out that is it empty or not. Also, make sure you already log out @ealeon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few problems with your code as it stands, so I'll try to clean it up with some comments as I would write it to add a review to a wine.

```
@login_required
def add_review(request, wine_id):
    wine = get_object_or_404(Wine, pk=wine_id)
    if request.POST:
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = ReviewForm()  
    if form.is_valid():
        ### NO NEED FOR - already set as part of valid modelform ::: rating = form.cleaned_data['rating']
        ### AS WELL AS ::: comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']

        ### THIS IS NOT A FIELD IN YOUR FORM :::user_name = form.cleaned_data['user_name']
        user_name = request.user.username
        review = form.save(commit=False) # commit = False means that this instantiate but not save a Review model object
        review.wine = wine
        review.user_name = user_name # Why use this instead of a ForeignKey to user?
        review.pub_date = datetime.datetime.now() # works as long as pub_date is a DateTimeField
        review.save() # save to the DB now
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('reviews:wine_detail', args=(wine.id,))) # THIS will redirect only upon form save
    return render(request, 'reviews/wine_detail.html', {'wine': wine, 'form': form})
```

Now, the error your seeing is most likely related to you passing `request.POST` to a form even if request.POST is blank; the form will attempt to set initial values but with a querydict that has no values that actually relates to the form.

**EDIT**: In response to your comments, my next step would be to try and render each form field individually and see if I can trigger a failure.

Instead of `{% bootstrap_form form layout='inline' %}`, try-

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% bootstrap_field field %}
{% endfor %}
```

If this is an error with the django-bootstrap library trying to render the textarea widget and the inline style together (as I would suspect at this point), you can also eliminate the widget parameter and see if there's a fix. If there is, I'd suggest overriding your modelform's **init** method for assign a widget post a call super on **init**.

Comment: As you can see in my view, request.POST is only passed to the form instantiation when supplied by the request.

Comment: that didnt fix it >.<

Comment: In that case I'd suggest you show the base.html template that your template extends. In order to troubleshoot on your own you should render view in a a plain fashion (not using the bootstrapform tag) or write a custom template-tag that displays the type of object that form is.

Comment: i added base.html. it says its not a 'valid' django form which mean something is wrong with review/forms.py. that would be my guess

Comment: I would guess this is an error with django-bootstrap using the custom TextArea widget; I added a suggestion for how I would investigate further above.

Comment: the loop made it work. I suppose the inline was the problem

Comment: Glad I could at least help with troubleshooting. Please not that you need to render {{ form.non_field_errors }} for the overall form and {% for error in field.errors %}{{ error }}{% endfor %} per field, as these are taken care of automatically when creating bootstrap_form as a whole. It's worth submitting a bug on Github; this is a widely used library and it can truly simplify things. And, if I helped you, please accept my answer. Thanks and happy Django-ing!

Answer (score 0):

**In Class Base View**

This error may occur when you use **form_class** in the **wrong generic view**.

⮕ Open your **views.py** then check to see if you have set the wrong generic view in your class.

**Example**

```
class ProfileUpdateView(T̶e̶m̶p̶l̶a̶t̶e̶V̶i̶e̶w̶ UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = forms.ProfileForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("stories:story_list")
    template_name = 'profile.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
         return get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.request.user.id)
```